# noframenumbering does not seem to work

Tags: beamer, errors, pdftex, kile

I have an issue in Kile 2.0.85 (It's my institute's computer, so I can't update it myself).

I have a beamer project for a presentation. I write:

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{2 Inputs}
```

and it seems to work (I don't see any errors or warning marking the option as unknown), but in the pdf presentation the counter of the slides increases nevertheless.

Anyone knows what the problem is? Outdated version of Kile or any other package? Maybe I have to include some extra package? Any other ideas?

Thanks.

(Note: I'm very new to the site. If the title, content, or tags of this question are inappropriate, feel free to edit, or to ask me additional information!)

**Edit:** Here is a minimal example. (Did I do it correctly?)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{default}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{2 Inputs}
 These should look like
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{2 Inputs}
 These should look like the same page 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

When I compile this example, the counters at the bottom right corner are increasing:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a Minimal Working Example, otherwise it will be difficult to users to answer your question. Please see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Is it just an issue of Kile? Does your tex-File compile as expected converting it without Kile?

Comment: @crixstox No, also pdflatex (from terminal) does the same.

Comment: @geodude Your MWE works fine and gives the expected result. Have you compiled it twice? If so, I guess that your beamer packages is too old. (I think that the option nuoframenumber was introduce in version 3.08)-

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as probably caused by old package version